# Unprotect sheet in foxpro

Tags: foxpro, excel-automation

I have an xlsm file that I need to insert data but my problem is that the xlsm in protected. I use the `oWorkbook.Protect(,,.F.)` to unprotect but the function is not working. I s there any way to unprotect the file using the foxpro?

```
oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
**checking if the excel installed into the computer
if vartype(oExcel) != "O"
    MESSAGEBOX("could not instantiate Excel object.")
  return .F.
ENDIF

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = .F.
oExcel.visible=.T.
**opening the data File
oWorkbook = oExcel.Application.workbooks.open(SYS(5)+SYS(2003)+"\WebADI Template\WebADI.xlsm")
**unprotect the workbook
oWorkbook.Protect(,,.F.)
```

Comment: Can you unprotect it in Excel? Is it protected with a password?

Comment: @AlanB Yes i can unprotect the file. I already save the xlsm in unprotect but when reopen the file will be protected. I think there are mechanizing in the macro when the will open it automatically protect the file.